# Error calling a method on react this._method(...).bind is not a function

Tags: reactjs

Hello I'm newbie on react and I'm starting creating my first component. It looks like this:

```
var React = require('react')
var ReactDom = require('react-dom')



class TestText extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const number1 = 6
        const number2 = 5

        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Hello World</h3>
                <p> The result of multiply {number1} and {number2} is {this._multiply(number1,number2).bind(this)}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }

    _multiply (num1, num2) {
        return num1*num2
    }
}

ReactDom.render(<TestText />, document.getElementById('test-container'))
```

When I try to open it on my browser it throws me the following error:

TypeError: this._multiply(...).bind is not a function

Any help with this? Thank you!

Comment: `this._multiply(number1,number2)` is not a function but a number so you cannot bind to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well,

- `this._multiply` is the function reference, where you can apply bind.
- `this._multiply(a, b)` returns the function result, which is a number.

You could use `this._multiply.bind(this, a, b)()` and that would be correct.
You can simplify the parenthesis and use `this._multiply.call(this, a, b)`.
However `this._multiply` does not use any `this` reference within the function, so there is no need to bind at all, and you can simply type:

`{this._multiply(a, b)}`

Comment: Thanks man! However this._multiply.call(this, a, b) doesn't return nothing so I have to call it with brackets this._multiply.call(this, a, b)()

Comment: Mmm, seems weird! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call is it a ES6 thing?