# Access state in an object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have declared a object in my state, se code:

```
this.state = {
  attendtext: "Attend",
  showPanel: false,
  attendespanel: null,
  user: this.user
};
```

I update it with the usual setState:

```
if (attenduser.isSiteAdmin) {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    user: {
      ...prevState.user,
      isSiteAdmin: true
    }
  }));
}
```

But I cant access this objects properties. For example:

```
this.state.user.isSiteAdmin
```

Above is not valid. How come?

My interface:

```js
export interface UserItem {
  Key?: string;
  Username?: string;
  user?: {
    title: string,
    emailaddress: string,
    isSiteAdmin: boolean
  };
}
```

I also tried to set the state with:

```
this.state = {
  attendtext: "Attend",
  showPanel: false,
  attendespanel: null,
  user: { title: "", emailaddress: "", isSiteAdmin: false }
};
```

However, it gets red "Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'title' does not exist in type 'UserItem[]'" which happens for all the properties in the user object, even if they are declared in the interface.

Comment: Where are you using `this`? It may be doing [something you didn't know about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: In a return function, inside the render.

Comment: You should try to bind "this", this may solve. For better explanation, please read @VLAZ URL. I also recommend reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37833757/10473393

Answer (score 2):

When you do,

```
this.state = {
  attendtext:"Attend",
  showPanel: false,
  attendespanel:null,
  //     
  user: this.user
}
```

`this.use` should be an instance variable of the component you are using `this.state`.
e.g.)

```
class App extends Component {
  user: {}
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {...}
  }
}
```

But then, whenever `App` component re-renders, `this.user` is reset (back to the initial empty object, `{}`), as it won't be managed by React.

So more appropriate way to declare the state is to include the `user` as part of the `this.state`, which React can manage (CRUD with `this.setState`)

```
this.state = {
  attendtext: "Attend",
  showPanel: false,
  attendespanel: null,
  user: { isSiteAdmin: false }
};
```

Now you can access `this.state.user.isSiteAdmin`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Clarified it a bit. But my interface doesn't like it for some reasons (added it to my original post).

Comment: Would you also add code for how `this.state.user.isSiteAdmin` is being accessed? It seems like `UserItem[]` is an array of `UserItem` and doesn't match exactly with `this.state.user`.